# get rid of "duplicates" in nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested hash:

```
given =  {
  "AA" => {
     :GE => nil,
    "GE" => "successful",
     :GR => nil,
     :ZG => nil,
    "ZG" => "successful",
  },
  "BB" => {
    :MM => nil,
    "MM" => "successful",
     :GR => nil,
     :ZZ => nil,
    "ZZ" => "successful",
  }
}
```

and my goal is to transform it into a new hash without the duplicates eg. :GE/"GE" and :ZG/"ZG" and so on.

```
goal = {
  "AA" => {
    :GE => "successful",
    :GR => nil,
    :ZG => "successful",
  },
  "BB" => {
    :MM => "successful",
     :GR => nil,
    :ZZ => "successful",
  }
}
```

My attempt is with Rails method index_by

```
given.map do |key, value|
  value.index_by {|r| value[r]}
end
```

Or with

```
given.each { |key,value| temp_hash = {} (value.each { |va| va[0].each { |k,v| temp_hash|key| << val }}) given_hash[k.to_sym] = temp_hash if given.has_key?(k.to_sym)}
```

But I'm kind of stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If @max's assumption is correct I suggest you edit your answer to make that clear (for example, "and my goal...and so on, removing the key whose value is `nil`").

Comment: oh, you're right! I didn't think of that. @max's answer works but I should have wait a little longer. Next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that in the case of `{ :GE => nil, "GE" => "successful" }`, you want to use the first truthy value ("successful") and make sure the key is a symbol:

```
result = given.transform_values do |inner_hsh|
  inner_hsh.group_by do |k,v|
    k.to_sym
  end.transform_values do |key_vals|
    key_vals.to_h.values.find(&:itself)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that @max's assumption is correct, and also that the order of the keys in inner hashes is not important, here is another way to produce the desired return value.

```
given.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = v.sort_by { |_,w| w.nil? ? 1 : 0 }.uniq { |m,_| m.to_s }.to_h
end
  #=> {"AA"=>{"GE"=>"successful", "ZG"=>"successful", :GR=>nil},
  #    "BB"=>{"MM"=>"successful", "ZZ"=>"successful", :GR=>nil}}
```

See [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq), particularly the sentence, "self is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.".

For

```
k = "AA"
v = { :GE=>nil, "GE"=>"successful", :GR=>nil, :ZG=>nil, "ZG"=>"successful" }
```

we compute

```
a = v.sort_by { |_,w| w.nil? ? 1 : 0 }
  #=> [["GE", "successful"], ["ZG", "successful"],
  #    [:GE, nil], [:GR, nil], [:ZG, nil]] 
b = a.uniq { |m,_| m.to_s }
  #=> [["GE", "successful"], ["ZG", "successful"], [:GR, nil]]
```

because `"GE"` precedes `:GE` and `"ZG"` precedes `:ZG`. Lastly,

```
h[k] = b.to_h
  #=> {"GE"=>"successful", "ZG"=>"successful", :GR=>nil}
```